# how to change normal table to IOT?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Actually I've created one table as

```
CREATE TABLE "ATR"."S_JOURNEY"
  (
    "TIMETABLE_ID"            NUMBER(*,0) primary key,
    "STATION_ID"              NUMBER(*,0),
    "SCHEDULE_ARRIVAL_TIME"   VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
    "SCHEDULE_DEPARTURE_TIME" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
    "OTHER_DETAILS"           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
  );
```

now i just want to create one index organized table like the same above.i can get by using

```
CREATE TABLE "ATR"."iot_S_JOURNEY"   organization index as select * from ATR.s_journey;
```

is there anyway to using `alter` command to change normal table as IOT.

thanks in advance

Comment: You might like to order by your primary key in the CTAS, just to optimise the insert process.

Comment: @ David Aldridge:can't get you dude!

Comment: So if you want to make maintenance of an index as cheap as possible when loading bulk data to the underlying table, you order the inserted data to match the index order. This reduces the size of the final index by promoting more efficient block splits, and reduces the total number of blocks modified during the load by not inserting into random leaf nodes. Same principle with an IOT -- by ordering the insert by the primary key value the maintenance of the structure is reduced, leading to a more compact IOT. Try a couple of tests, ordering by PK and then by a random value.

Comment: @David Aldridge:ya sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to use an `alter table` to transform a heap table into an IOT.

What you're doing with a CATS statement is probably the easiest way of doing it. The other two usual methods would be:

- export the table data, recreate the structure as an IOT, then import the data
- use online table redefinition. The [Redefining Tables Online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/tables007.htm) docs explicitly state that `RDBMS_REDEFINITION` enables you to:

  > Change the organization of a normal table (heap organized) to an index-organized table, or do the reverse.

That second option is more complex, but that's the only way to do it online as far as I know. Do make sure you test it out on non-critical systems first, including generating concurrent modifications if that's what will happen when you do it live.

Comment: so there is no command like alter table <table_name> organized by index?

Comment: thanks dude..i general we can't alter the existing heap table to IOT right!i mean we need to make copy of it?

Comment: The three usual ways of doing it are the one you did, the export/import, and the redefinition as I put in my answer.